# How do I change the candidates for ido-completing read based on the input?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have a list of candidates for an ido-completing-read call that represent all the installed python modules on my system. I would like to type in a name, then a . and have the list of candidates change to say the classes/functions available in just that module. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about `ido-completing-read`, but in general in completion tables you do that by implementing your completion table as a *function* which takes 3 arguments `(STRING PRED ACTION)` where *STRING* is the current prefix to complete, `*PRED* is the predicate that was passed to the completing-read function (if you don't pass such a predicate, you can ignore this argument), and *ACTION* is the operation to do.

The function is better thought of as an OO-style *object*, where the *ACTION* argument is the *method*.  There are several methods you need to implement (list all completions, find the current best completion, test a completion, return the boundaries corresponding to the "list all completions" (e.g. if your "list all completions" method on "a.b" returns a list like `("bob" "baby")` rather than `("a.bob" "a.baby")` then your completion *boundaries* on "a.b" should be placed around the "b")).

See the `(elisp)Programmed Completion` node for more detailed documentation.  You might also want to look at the `completion-file-name-table` function's source code, since that's the completion table used for file-name completion which uses that same behavior you're looking for.